# Why Faraday homopolar generator need brushes?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

It is said that if one would attach a load physically to the rotating disc from center to rim no current would flow because both in the load wires and the disc itself currents would be generated in the same directions, everything would cancel out, right?

But I don't understand why this is a problem? there is a simple workaround: The wires can lead out of the field or extend far away from the magnetic field range, like so:[image]

The blue arrows symbolize induced force vectors when disc with shaft and wires rotates, current should flow from the rim to the center of the disc just like in Faraday brushed version, the upper part of the shaft and the wire does not cut the field lines.

However I have build this and no EMF was detected, I don't understand why, the voltage induced in the shaft should not block the current coming from the rim to the center of the disc?

Comment: How did you try to measure the emf ?

Comment: Bluetooth transmitter+amp  and receiver + scope.

Comment: Your drawing would indicate that you had a bar magnet as the source of the magnetic field. The homopolar generators I have seen have their disk between the poles of a $\mathbf U$ magnet, that would give you a much stronger field that points nearly perpendicular to the disk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator

Comment: Its a round magnet and yes I have seen other homopolar generators, my version works with brushes just fine, I don't understand why I have no emf when wires ale soldered to the disc, the shaft is charged in the same way that disc is,  like a radial capacitor but it still should let the disc current flow from the rim to the center...

Comment: Is the entire contraption (minus the magnet) rotating, including the load?

Comment: The resistance in sum seems to be to high?

Comment: entire contraption rotates.

Comment: I mean the electrical resistance

Comment: resistance is low and amplifier can detect tiny currents.